# Laravel 5.8 Deploy shared hosting 500 Server Error

Tags: php, laravel

I've recently upgraded to laravel 5.8 and have deployed many laravel sites on shared hosting. This time something is wrong. The site (home page) loads but once I want to login I get to 500 Server Error.

Domain is https://attela.co.za

Here is my log file:

```
[stacktrace]
#0 /usr/home/myserver/laravel/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'include(/usr/ho...', '/usr/home/attel...', 444, Array)
#1 /usr/home/myserver/laravel/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#2 /usr/home/myserver/laravel/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/usr/home/myser...')
#3 [internal function]: Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#4 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#5 /usr/home/myserver/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(788): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
```

Comment: What is the actual error? The stack trace is not enough. But from the looks of it, the composer autoloader can't resolve some class. The actual error message should shed some light on what that is.

Comment: The only error I get id to 500 Server error. I have enabled php error and it doesn't provide any clue.

Comment: It looks like it might be having issues loading a middleware class. But without the full paths, it makes it hard to diagnose.

Comment: Do you have any paths hard coded? It looks like it's trying to load files from both `'/usr/home/myser...'` and `'/usr/home/attel...'`. Whichever one is not your current working directory is where it's probably throwing the error.

Comment: @StuartHarrison the stack trace you posted from your error log should be preceded by an error message. We are asking for that error message which describes the actual error.

Comment: [2019-09-17 12:34:36] production.ERROR: include(/usr/home/myserver/laravel/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): include(/usr/home/myserver/laravel/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /usr/home/myserver/laravel/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444)
[stacktrace]

Comment: This only happens when the route has auth as middleware.. Any suggestions?

Comment: NEVER TRUST FILE UPLOADS. For some reason FileZilla decided not to upload some files in my app folder. After I uploaded it everything is working!